# Where are screen recordings saved from a cancelled share?

Tags: video, screen-capture, quicktime, ventura

I took a long recording of my entire screen using the [Screenshot Toolbar](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208721). Afterward, I clicked the "share" button so I could send my recording elsewhere, and clicked the "Dropbox" option. Because of an issue, I realized that I wanted to upload the video straight to YouTube instead of sharing it Dropbox, so I closed the Dropbox window.

However, after closing the Dropbox popup window, when I go to upload the video online, I can no longer find where the screen recording is saved on my computer. It does not appear on my Desktop anywhere, nor does it seem to appear in Finder. (I have my screen recordings Option set to "Desktop", which I later have found seems to work fine when I click the "Done" button instead of sharing.) **Where can I find the default save location for my recordings when I close out of a "Share" interface like Dropbox before it starts uploading anything?**

I'm running Ventura v13.3.1.

Thanks!